# Redirect denied connections from ports 80 and 443 to a 403 page

Tags: proxy, firewall, connection, ufw, port-forwarding

I have a server that is running sniproxy. I have ufw as a firewall, which I use to allow certain IPs to use the proxy. However, I need to send the denied attemps to a 403 Forbidden page. Can someone help me accomplish this?

I appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: Which Ubuntu release your server is running?

Comment: We need to know how you configured your proxy and how you are trying to redirect.

Comment: Also I would use squid =)

Comment: Thank you @bodhi.zazen!! I apologize, I am so new to this.. Sniproxy is configured to listen on ports 80 and 443. It is set to proxy all incoming traffic on those 2 ports. It does not have access authentication capabilities. So, I use ufw to easily allow from IP when I want to give access to an IP. However, when an IP that is not registered tries to use the proxy, no website is reachable, as that IP is denied access by ufw. What I want to do is display a 403 page. Ideally, I would like to redirect the request to another server at port 80 that shows a forbidden access page.

Comment: I have considered squid. But I kinda understood that it does not have sni capabilities, and it would display certificate errors on the client web browser for 443 requests.

Comment: How do you server your 403  page ? Do you have a web server ?

Comment: Squid is a better tool for what you want. https://www.howtoforge.com/filtering-https-traffic-with-squid https://serverfault.com/questions/785034/how-to-properly-setup-squid3-as-https-proxy